# MikTeX Archive Corruption ( 敺捶潲獳猭牣灩獴漮瑵)⠠敺捶潲獳猭牣灩獴漮瑵 )

Tags: pdftex, miktex2.9

I have been using Knitr, R, and LaTeX to typeset some source code with the resulting R graphic in an effort to learn R, ggplot2 and Knitr and today I started to see this:

`("C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fmtcount\fc-english.def")
("C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"⤩⠠敺捶潲獳猭牣灩獴漮瑵)⠠敺捶潲獳猭牣灩獴漮瑵)
("C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\emerald\ot1fau.fd")`

in the console window output but not in the log file. Specifically, the Chinese characters only appear in the console. MikTeX was just updated to most current, using R 3.4.3 with latest knitr, WinEdt 10.2.

Does anyone know what's going on? Is `pdflatex.exe` compromised?

Comment: How is the name of you main file?

Comment: The file is: C:\Users\dave\Documents\R\ZevRoss chicago nmmaps\zevcross-scripts.Rnw which knitr produces zevcross-scripts.tex . Note that everything was fine until I updated MikTeX Thursday morning (package bidi). The Chinese characters were not being shown before...they really stand out in WinEdt's console. Can I get a fresh version of pdflatex.exe ? I have run numerous AVG scans with no results found. Also, Tuesday I updated (bidi, microtype, tcolorbox, unicode-math) MikTeX.

Comment: Can you show the content of the tex-file?

Comment: Also which console are you using? It is the cmd window or something from an editor?

Comment: It's the console from WinEdt 10.2 . The source of the .Rnw file is 825 lines and the knit'd .tex file is 1629 lines long. I could zip them and either attach to something or email them. How could I get them to you? Thanks for your interest.

Comment: My email is easy to find. But I'm away now and can't looking at it before Monday.